# Javascript loop executes in the wrong order

Tags: javascript, arrays, html-lists, nested-loops

I have a `function` where I want to create an `unordered list` from an `array`. The `array` is nested and so another `<ul>` has to be created after a new `array` started. The function works, but there is only one problem: the `unordered list` doesn't get displayed in the right order. I don't know why because I made the same `function` in `PHP` and there it is displayed in the right order. The `array` looks as follows:

```
 $topics = [
     'Aanwezigen / afwezigen',
     'Toevoegingen agenda',
     'Update openstaande actiepunten',
     'Marketing' => [
        'Website',
        'Social media',
        'Nieuwsbrief',
     ],
     'Acquisitie' => [
        'Leads',
        'Deals',
        'Netwerk',
     ],
     'Inkoop' => [
        'Leveranciers',
        'Marges',
     ],
     'Jaarrekening 2018',
     'Komende periode',
     'Oplezen actiepunten',
     'Rondvraag',
];
```

This is my `Javascript function`:

```
let HTML = "<ul>";

for (const [key, value] of topics) {
  if (Array.isArray(value)) {
    HTML = HTML + "<li>" + key + "</li>";

    for (let i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
      HTML = HTML + "<ul>";
      HTML = HTML + "<li>" + value[i] + "</li>";
      HTML = HTML + "</ul>";
    }
  } else {
    HTML = HTML + "<li>" + value + "</li>";
  }
}
```

The output of `HTML` is this:

- Aanwezigen / afwezigen
- Toevoegingen agenda
- Update openstaande actiepunten
- Jaarrekening 2018
- Komende periode
- Oplezen actiepunten
- Rondvraag
- Marketing

  - Website
  - Social media
  - Nieuwsbrief
- Acquisitie

  - Leads
  - Deals
  - Netwerk
- Inkoop

  - Leveranciers
  - Marges

As you can see it places the `HTML` generated in the `if-statement` at the end of the `unordered list` while it shouldn't. Any advice on how to tackle this problem? Or any explanation why it doesn't work the same as it does in `PHP`?

**Update:**

When I `console.log` the `array` `topics`, it looks like this:

```
(10) [Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2)]
0: (2) ["0", "Aanwezigen / afwezigen"]
1: (2) ["1", "Toevoegingen agenda"]
2: (2) ["2", "Update openstaande actiepunten"]
3: (2) ["3", "Jaarrekening 2018"]
4: (2) ["4", "Komende periode"]
5: (2) ["5", "Oplezen actiepunten"]
6: (2) ["6", "Rondvraag"]
7: Array(2)
0: "Marketing"
1: (3) ["Website", "Social media", "Nieuwsbrief"]
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
8: Array(2)
0: "Acquisitie"
1: (3) ["Leads", "Deals", "Netwerk"]
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
9: Array(2)
0: "Inkoop"
1: (2) ["Leveranciers", "Marges"]
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
length: 10
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Comment: How does `topics` variable in JS looks like? The one you posted above is in PHP

Comment: I updated my answer @Saharsh. Seems like the order isn't right there already. I created the `topics` `array` like this: `const topics = Object.entries(response.data);`. Where `response.data` is the `array` as I got it from `PHP`

Comment: Seems like array order got distorted way before this loop was executed. Try checking your response as well.

Comment: @Baspa The order of the array returned by Object.entries() does not depend on how an object is defined. If there is a need for certain ordering then the array should be sorted first like ```Object.entries(obj).sort((a, b) => b[0].localeCompare(a[0]));``` See [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)

Comment: Tou are trying to iterate a PHP nested array in JavaScript. Use a JavaScript object instwad, like **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58190563/4512005)**  for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to change your function apart from changing the data from json to array.

Your function should something like below.

```
for (const value of topics) {

  if (Array.isArray(value) && value.length > 1) {
    HTML = HTML + "<li>" + value[0] + "</li>";

    for (let i = 0; i < value[1].length; i++) {
      HTML = HTML + "<ul>";
      HTML = HTML + "<li>" + value[1][i] + "</li>";
      HTML = HTML + "</ul>";
    }
  } else {
    HTML = HTML + "<li>" + value[0] + "</li>";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a Javascript object. Iterate it like this:

```js
let data = {
  topics: [{
      name: 'Aanwezigen/afwezigen'
    },
    {
      name: 'Toevoegingen agenda'
    },
    {
      name: 'Update openstaande actiepunten'
    },
    {
      name: 'Marketing',
      subtopics: [
        'Website',
        'Social media',
        'Nieuwsbrief',
      ]
    },
    {
      name: 'Acquisitie',
      subtopics: [
        'Leads',
        'Deals',
        'Netwerk',
      ]
    },
    {
      name: 'Inkoop',
      subtopics: [
        'Leveranciers',
        'Marges',
      ]
    },
    {
      name: 'Jaarrekening 2018'
    },
    {
      name: 'Komende periode'
    },
    {
      name: 'Oplezen actiepunten'
    },
    {
      name: 'Rondvraag'
    }
  ]
};

let container = document.getElementById('container');

const topics = data.topics;

if (topics) {
  var list = '<ul class="list">';
  topics.forEach(function(topic) {
    list = list + "<li>" + topic.name + "</li>";
    if (topic.hasOwnProperty('subtopics')) {
      var sublist = '<ul class="sublist">';
      var subtopics = topic.subtopics;
      for (var i = 0; i < subtopics.length; i++) {
        sublist = sublist + '<li>' + subtopics[i] + '</li>';
      };
      sublist = sublist + '</ul>';
    } else {
      var sublist = '';
    }
    list = list + sublist;
  });
  list = list + '</ul>';
  container.innerHTML = list;
} else {
  container.innerHTML = '<p>There are no topics</p>';
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Be aware that JSON has objects and arrays, whereas PHP conflates the two into a single type. JSON does not preserve the order of objects; if you want the order, be sure to use arrays (i.e. using consecutive numerical indices in PHP, no string keys). This would involve restructuring your array. For example, a list of items, where each item consists of a name and list of children:

```
$topics = [
     ['Aanwezigen / afwezigen'],
     ['Toevoegingen agenda'],
     ['Update openstaande actiepunten'],
     ['Marketing', [
        'Website',
        'Social media',
        'Nieuwsbrief',
     ]],
     ['Acquisitie', [
        'Leads',
        'Deals',
        'Netwerk',
     ]],
     ['Inkoop', [
        'Leveranciers',
        'Marges',
     ]],
     ['Jaarrekening 2018'],
     ['Komende periode'],
     ['Oplezen actiepunten'],
     ['Rondvraag'],
];
```

This structure will preserve the order, and is easy to iterate on in JavaScript.

Comment: I tried this structure but it didn't preserve the order, I got the same output as before.

Comment: It is literally impossible to get the same output as before, unless you’ve edited the wrong part of your code or cache interfered. For one thing, you would have to also have adapted the JavaScript.